# Multivariate bayesian parameter estimation

Tags: bayesian, posterior, pymc

I am implementing an example for pymc3 in python and I want to understand the mathematical formulation of this code.

```
# Create random sample.
y_observations = np.random.normal(loc=0.5, scale=0.35, size=2000)

# Create pymc3 model.
with pm.Model() as exercise1:

  # Prior distributions
  standard_deviation = pm.HalfNormal('sigma', sd=1.0)
  mean = pm.Normal('mu', mu=0.0, sd=1.0)

  y = pm.Normal('y', mu=mean, sd=standard_deviation, observed=y_observations)

  # Running Markov Chain Monte Carlo
  trace = pm.sample(1000)
  
  pm.traceplot(trace, ['mu', 'sigma'])
  plt.show()
```

> **Question**: I am trying to formulate the task of the code as a mathematical procedure. I wanted to know if my understanding of the
> underlying mathematics behind the code is correct.

**My attempt to put the code into mathematical language**:

The data $\mathcal{D} = \{y_1, \ldots, y_N\}$ is assumed to be independent and identically distributed (short i.i.d.). The underlying distribution is the normal distribution

$$y \sim \mathcal{N}(y|\mu, \sigma).$$

Hence, the two parameters are $\mu$ and $\sigma$. The prior is given by
$$p(\mu,\sigma) = \mathcal{N}(\mu| 0, 1) \cdot \mathcal{N}_+(\sigma|0, 1),$$

in which $\mathcal{N}_+(\sigma|0, 1)$ is the half-normal distribution. The mathematical formulation is given by

$$\mathcal{N}_+(\sigma|0, 1) = 2 \mathcal{N}(\sigma|0, 1)\text{ , for }\sigma \geq 0$$

Note that we assumed stochastic independence between $\mu$ and $\sigma$ by applying $p(\mu,\sigma) = p(\mu) \cdot p(\sigma)$.

The likelihood $p(\mathcal{D}|\mu, \sigma)$ can be written as

$$p(\mathcal{D}|\mu, \sigma) = \prod_{n=1}^N\mathcal{N}(y_n|\mu, \sigma),$$

if we apply the i.i.d. property.

Hence, the posterior distribution $p(\mu, \sigma | \mathcal{D})$ is given by

$$p(\mu, \sigma | \mathcal{D}) = \dfrac{p(\mathcal{D}|\mu, \sigma)p(\mu,\sigma)}{\int_{\mu=-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{\sigma=0}^{\infty}p(\mathcal{D}|\mu, \sigma)p(\mu,\sigma)d\sigma d\mu}$$
$$= \dfrac{\prod_{n=1}^N\mathcal{N}(y_n|\mu, \sigma)\mathcal{N}(\mu| 0, 1) \cdot \mathcal{N}_+(\sigma|0, 1)}{\int_{\mu=-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{\sigma=0}^{\infty}\prod_{n=1}^N\mathcal{N}(y_n|\mu, \sigma)\mathcal{N}(\mu| 0, 1) \cdot \mathcal{N}_+(\sigma|0, 1)d\sigma d\mu}.$$

The Markov Chain Monte Carlo (MCMC) algorithm samples parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$ from this posterior distribution and counts how often a specific value (or interval) for $\mu$ and $\sigma$ is selected to generate the plots on the left-hand side.

[image]

Comment: I can't spot any issues with your understanding

Comment: @alan ocallaghan: Thank you for your feedback.